# Testing Apex Code, Lightning. Possible error in docs?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

In the `Lightning Components Developer Guide` documentation on [Testing Your Apex Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apps_packaging_tests.htm), it gives this code example:

> ```
> @isTest
> class TestExpenseController {
>     static testMethod void test() {
>         //Create new expense and insert it into the database        
>         Expense__c exp = new Expense__c(name='My New Expense',
>                          amount__c=20, client__c='ABC',
>                          reimbursed__c=false, date__c=null);
>         ExpenseController.saveExpense(exp);
>      // ^^This line here*******************
>
>     //Assert the name field and saved expense
>     System.assertEquals('My New Expense',
>                        ExpenseController.getExpenses()[0].Name,
>                       'Name does not match');
>     System.assertEquals(exp, ExpenseController.saveExpense(exp));
>     }
> }
> ```

What's the purpose of that line of code that I commented below it? The reason I ask is it was throwing errors when I replicated it in my test class.

Here is my test class

```
@isTest
class WhiteboardItemsApexControllerTest {
    static testMethod void newWhiteboardItemDBTest() {

    User u      = new User();
    u.UserName  = 'FirstName.LastName@company.com';
    u.Email     = 'FirstName.LastName@company.com';
    u.FirstName = 'FirstName';
    u.LastName  = 'LastName';
    u.Alias     = 'flast';
    u.ProfileId = '00ed0000000uSiX';

    u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'GMT';
    u.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
    u.EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1';
    u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
    u.UserPermissionsMobileUser = false;

    insert u;

    TouchpointDev__Whiteboard_Item__c item = new TouchpointDev__Whiteboard_Item__c (
        Name = 'Test Item',
        TouchpointDev__Item_Due_Date__c = Date.today(),
        TouchpointDev__AssignedTo__c = u.Id,
        TouchpointDev__High_Priority__c = false,
        TouchpointDev__PersonalItem__c = true,
        TouchpointDev__Completed__c = false
    );

    WhiteboardItemsApexController.newWhiteboardItemDB(item);
//  ^^When I comment out this line I don't get the error.    

    System.assertEquals(item,  WhiteboardItemsApexController.newWhiteboardItemDB(item));
    }
}
```

This is the error

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0 with id a00d000000k2r8tAAA; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]

Here is newWhiteboardItemDB method on the Apex class I'm testing

```
 @AuraEnabled
public static TouchpointDev__Whiteboard_Item__c newWhiteboardItemDB(TouchpointDev__Whiteboard_Item__c whiteboardItem) {

    insert whiteboardItem;

    return whiteboardItem;
}
```

Comment: What's in method newWhiteboardItemDB? You might inserting record with id, which is not allowed.

Comment: I added the newWhiteboardItemDB method to my original post. Sorry I didn't do that originally.

Comment: you're inserting same record two times. Remove your assert, it doesn't make any sense

Comment: That's what the docs example does though.

Comment: It's out of order in the documentation. They insert it twice in the documentation and the asserts are out of order, if you don't insert it before the asserts

Comment: they're doing [upsert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_records_save.htm)

Comment: Oh wow,  that's it. I think they need to give the full method being used on that doc page.

Comment: @IlyaLepesh Do you want to post that as the answer to get the credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error that you have:

> cannot specify Id in an insert call

Tells that you're trying to insert record which already has id. This operation is not allowed.
you can modify `insert` call in method `newWhiteboardItemDB` to `upsert`.
If you refer to Lightning test [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_records_save.htm), you'll found that they are doing upsert in their example:

```
public static Expense__c saveExpense(Expense__c expense) {
    // Perform isUpdateable() check here 
    upsert expense;
    return expense;
}
```